# disconnect vertices

Tags: vertices

these vertices became connected so that when the mouth moves these stretch, giving it the fang effect in the below pic. I already tried editing the weights for the bones but that doesn't seem to be the issue. how do i disconnect these vertices at the point they are connected at and maintain the architecture of the lips?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

answered my own question, i hit V and they disconnected